# Python pass multiple classes to function/method/

Tags: python, class, methods, neural-network

I am trying to write the `derivative` function given in pseudo code in my mwe below. It is supposed to calculate the numerical derivative of the cost of the prediction of my neural network with respect to a parameter of one of its layers.

My problem is I don't know how to pass and access an instance of NeuralNetwork and an instance of Layer from within the function (or method?) at the same time.

Looking into e.g. [Passing a class to another class (Python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30005672/passing-a-class-to-another-class-python) did not provide an answer to me.

```
import copy


class NeuralNetwork:
    def __init__(self):
        self.first_layer = Layer()
        self.second_layer = Layer()

    def cost(self):
        # not the actual cost but not of interest
        return self.first_layer.a + self.second_layer.a


class Layer:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 1


''' pseudocode
def derivative(NeuralNetwork, Layer):
    stepsize = 0.01
    cost_unchanged = NeuralNetwork.cost()
    NN_deviated = copy.deepcopy(NeuralNetwork)
    NN_deviated.Layer.a += stepsize
    cost_deviated = NN_deviated.cost()
    return (cost_deviated - cost_unchanged)/stepsize 
'''

NN = NeuralNetwork()

''' pseudocode
derivative_first_layer = derivative(NN, first_layer)
derivative_second_layer = derivative(NN, second_layer)
'''
```

Comment: Can you explain what you want the `NN_current.Layer.a = 2` part to do?

Comment: I clarified the summary and changed the parameter to `NN_deviated.Layer.a += stepsize`